# Fetching data from Json

Tags: php, json

I have a json object. I need to get the values after decoding the json object.

However, some values are blank at times. This brings an error to the way I am fetching.

Kindly see below and advice.

```
$json = '{
  "Customers": {
    "IdentityStrings": [
      {
        "UniqueSystemIdentifier": "202000000000007004",
        "MSISDN": "211920494162",
        "FirstName": "Donald",
        "MiddleName": {

        },
        "LastName": "Twesiga",
        "DateOfBirth": "2000-01-01",
        "DateIdentityActivated": "20170816153810",
        "DateIdentityRegistered": "20170816153448",
        "OperatorNameRegisteredBy": {

        },

      }
    ]
  },
}';
```

To get the values, I json decode and fetch as below.

```
$jsonData = json_decode($json);

   foreach ($jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0] as $key => $value) {

        $UniqueSystemIdentifier = ($jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->UniqueSystemIdentifier);
        $MSISDN = ($jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->MSISDN);
        $FirstName = ($jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->FirstName);
        $MiddleName = ($jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->MiddleName);
        $LastName = $jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->LastName;
        $DateOfBirth = $jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->DateOfBirth;
        $OperatorNameRegisteredBy = $jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->OperatorNameRegisteredBy;


    }
```

The problem comes when some are empty like in this case `MiddleName` and `OperatorNameRegisteredBy`.

How can I fetch in case they have values or not?

Thank you.

Comment: your json is invalid. when in doubt, paste it at **[jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)**.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I think he only pasted partial Json, and forgot to remove the trailing commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ternary conditions so that you can get rid of the error;

```
$MSISDN = (isset($jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->MSISDN) && !empty($jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->MSISDN))? $jsonData->Customers->IdentityStrings[0]->MSISDN : "";
```

So the same for all the values.